# How to send a message from node A to node B and then receive another msg from node B to node A in OMNET++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

How to send a message from node A to node B and then receive another msg from node B to node A in OMNET++ ?

Answer (score 0):

To send a message one should use `send()` method. Take a look at [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part1/), it contains a simple example of sending as well as receiving message.